# Rails 3.2.1 redirect_to options hash not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

Using Rails :**3.2.1**, Ruby: **ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]**.

My **HelloController.rb#sign_in** method 
validates the credentials (form-values) received.If validation fails, it render **login_page**.

Once validation is successful, authenticates the user credentials
If credentials found correct, redirect to **Games#index** else redirect to **"/hello/login_page"**

In my case following works

```
redirect_to "/games" # works
```

while the one below does not work

```
redirect_to {controller:"games", action:"index"} # Doesn't work
```

The latter case shows me an error like:
            URL: http://localhost:3000/hello/sign_in

```
        Output:
        Routing Error

        No route matches [GET] "/hello/sign_in"
```

However using the the same style of options for redirect from my **UsersController.rb#create** method, redirect works fine.

Also if credentials are not found correct, though validated, I need to show the user the login page with a message that userid/password doesn't match.In this case following works

```
  redirect_to "/hello/login_page", :notice => "User Id and Password don't match" # works
```

while following doesn't work

```
  redirect_to {controller:"hello", action:"login_page" notice: "User Id and Password don't match" } # Doesn't work
```

*I would like to understand what is the reason behind such behavior.*

Following is the code I have in place:

**routes.rb**

```
MyGames::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users do
    # Collection route
    collection do
        get 'register' # creates the register_users_url and register_users_path route helpers.
    end
  end

  resources :games

  get "hello/index"
  get "hello/login_page"
  post "hello/sign_in"

end
```

**HelloController.rb** (Manually created controller)

```
    class HelloController < ApplicationController

      skip_before_filter :require_login
      skip_before_filter :require_admin_role


      def index
            # Show index page
      end


      def login_page
        self.page_title = "Log In"

      end

      def sign_in

         # Validates the credentials.If validation fails
         # render "login_page"

         # Once validation is successful, authenticates the user credentials
         # If credentials found correct, redirect to Games#index
         # else redirect to "/hello/login_page"

         # In my case following works

         # redirect_to "/games", while

         # the one below does not work

         # redirect_to {controller:"games", action:"index"} # Doesn't work

      end

      private

      def page_title=(page_title)
          @page_title = page_title
      end

    end
```

**GamesController.rb** (Scaffold-generated controller)

```
    class GamesController < ApplicationController

      # This is the only piece I have added
      skip_before_filter :require_admin_role, :only => [:index]

      # GET /games
      # GET /games.json
      def index

      end

      # GET /games/1
      # GET /games/1.json
      def show

      end

      # GET /games/new
      # GET /games/new.json
      def new

      end

      # GET /games/1/edit
      def edit

      end

      # POST /games
      # POST /games.json
      def create

      end

      # PUT /games/1
      # PUT /games/1.json
      def update

      end

      # DELETE /games/1
      # DELETE /games/1.json
      def destroy

      end
    end
```

**UsersController.rb** (Scaffold-generated controller)

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

      skip_before_filter :require_login, :require_admin_role, :only => [:register, :create]

      # GET /users
      # GET /users.json
      def index

      end

      # GET /users/1
      # GET /users/1.json
      def show

      end

      # GET /users/new
      # GET /users/new.json
      def new

      end

      # GET /users/register
      def register 
        @user = User.new
      end

      # GET /users/1/edit
      def edit

      end

      # POST /users
      # POST /users.json
      def create  # Customized by me

        @user = User.new(params[:user])

        @user.role = 0 if @user.role.nil?

        action_identifier = params[:action_identifier]

        is_valid = @user.valid?
        validation_result_options = get_validation_result_options(is_valid, action_identifier)

        if is_valid
           @user.save(:validate => false)

           validation_result_options[:id] = @user.id if action_identifier != registration_action_identifier

           # Save the user ID in the session so it can be used in
           # subsequent requests
           session[:current_user_id] = @user.id

           # In this case it works correctly, by redirecting to '/games'
           # when 'registration' action is found.
           # The returned options are {  controller: "games", action: "index" }
           # which becomes 
           # redirect_to {  controller: "games", action: "index" }

           redirect_to validation_result_options 
        else
           render validation_result_options
        end

      end

      # PUT /users/1
      # PUT /users/1.json
      def update

      end

      # DELETE /users/1
      # DELETE /users/1.json
      def destroy

      end

      private

      def get_validation_result_options(is_valid, action_identifier)
        if is_valid
            options = case action_identifier
                       when registration_action_identifier
                         {  controller: "games", action: "index" }
                       else
                         {  action: "show", notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
                       end
        else
            options = case action_identifier
                       when registration_action_identifier
                            {  action: "register" }
                       else
                            {  action: "new" }
                       end
        end

        options
      end

      def registration_action_identifier
        "registration"
      end
    end
```

**ApplicationController.rb** (Scaffold-generated controller)

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery

      # Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters
      before_filter :require_login
      before_filter :require_admin_role

      # private methods are accessible by sub-classes
      private


      def current_user
        @_current_user ||= session[:current_user_id] && User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id])
      end

      def require_login
        unless logged_in?
            redirect_to controller: "hello", action: "login_page", notice: "You must be logged in to access this section"
        end
      end

      def require_admin_role
         unless is_admin?
            redirect_to controller: "hello", action: "login_page", notice: "You must have admin role to execute this action"
         end        
      end

      def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?
      end

      def is_admin?
        logged_in? && current_user.role == 1
      end

    end
```

Thanks,

Jignesh

Comment: Have you considered using the named routes?

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about named routes in [the rails guide's article about routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

- You could do something like `redirect_to game_path(@game)` to target the show action for the game controller, and
- `redirect_to games_path(notice: "Some notice..")` to redirect to the index action with a notice.

Comment: For RESTful routes using the helpers available like games_path etc there occurs no problem.However in case of manually created controller only I face the error and my question is more towards using a Hash literal with the redirect_to method.As mentioned in my post redirect_to {controller:"games", action:"index"} doesn't work while redirect_to "/games" works.Why is it that when passing a Hash Literal the feature doesn't work? The API clearly states that this method can accept a Hash http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to . Thanks.